# How to shorten code when there are many setOnClickListeners() in Kotlin-android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, data-binding

I am creating a calculator. But there are too many `setOnClickListeners()` making it harder to progress. This belongs to a fragment and it also has a ViewModel. I am using dataBinding here.
If there is any way I can write less code in the below mentioned context.

if there is any confusion about the question, please write in the comment. If my approach is wrong, share in the comments

### MY code:

```kotlin
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.calculatorViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        viewModel.currentExpression.value = "814×122" //temporary value
        viewModel.currentResult.value = "99308" //temporary value
        binding.etInput.doAfterTextChanged {
            viewModel.currentExpression.value = it.toString()
            binding.tvOutputPreview.text = viewModel.currentExpression.value
        }
        binding.apply {
            // Extra operators - setOnClickListener
            btnClear.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onClear() }
            btnAllClear.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onAllClear() }
            btnPlusMinus.setOnClickListener {  }
            btnEqual.setOnClickListener {  }

            // Operators - setOnClickListener
            btnDivide.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.mountOperator(btnDivide.text) }
            btnMultiply.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnMultiply.text) }
            btnMinus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnMinus.text) }
            btnPlus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnPlus.text) }


            //Secondary operators - setOnClickListener
            btnPercent.setOnClickListener {  }
            btnDecimal.setOnClickListener {  }

            // Numbers - setOnClickListener
            btn0Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn1Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn2Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn3Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn4Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn5Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn6Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn7Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn8Num.setOnClickListener {  }
            btn9Num.setOnClickListener {  }



        }
        binding.btnClear.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onClear() }
        binding.btnAllClear.setOnClickListener { viewModel.onAllClear() }
        binding.btnPlusMinus.setOnClickListener {  }


    }
```

Comment: Your code seems ok to me, it's not too many `clickListeners` if you can't work without them.

Comment: I'd say the same, it is not too many. There are a lot of buttons to be clicked, hence a lot of click listeners. What surprises me is that you use data binding, but it seems you are not setting values (or click listeners for that matter) in XML

Comment: @Michiel I am actually using databinding to implement LiveData, so that I can perform most of my work in the ViewModel class. Can you please explain what I am doing wrong with databinding as I don't understand you point

Comment: There is one-way view binding and two-way [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#data-binding). You fi. call `binding.tvOutputPreview.text = viewModel.currentExpression.value` in Kotlin, but with data binding one would normally set this in XML. Though, I haven't seen the XML of course, could well be that you using data binding in some cases - which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's okay to have too many click listeners.

but what you can do to make it look cleaner is you can set the click listener to this fragment or activity.

for example:

```
btn0Num.setOnClickListener(this)
```

and then implement View.OnClickListener in your class

and override the onClick method.

```
  override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    v?.let { 
        when(it){
            btn0Num -> {
              //Todo do something when the button is clicked
            }
            btn1Num -> {
              //Todo do something when the button is clicked
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this cleaner though? It goes from one line - `btn9Num.setOnClickListener { viewModel.actionFor9() }` to two lines, setting the listener and the when branch. This doubles the amount of code; I'd leave the current code as is.

Comment: @michiel ofc it's cleaner because the first thing programmer will look at is the onCreate function you don't want him to see all the functions and what the buttons do right away

Comment: This is just an opinion though, there is no inherent right or wrong. I would certainly not reject a PR over it, but I also do not think it is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Calculator crew today is it

I just posted this on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69337928/13598222), but if you have repetitive code like that, use a loop!

```
listOf(btnDivide, btnMultiply, btnMinus, btnPlus).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener { //bla bla }
}
```

In this case, since your buttons are logically grouped and you might need to refer to a group again, you might want to keep those lists around as a top-level variable:

```
// lateinit so we don't have to assign it yet, just make sure it's set
// before it's read!
lateinit var digitButtons: List<Button>

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    with(binding) {
        digitButtons = listOf(btn0Num, btn1Num...)
    }
}
```

then you can refer to it with things like `digitButtons.forEach`, or `if (button in digitButtons)` etc

---

If you're worried about creating so many click listeners, you can reuse a function:

```
fun handleClick(view: View) {
    // do the stuff
}

digitButtons.forEach {
    setOnClickListener { handleClick(it) }
}
// or with a function reference instead of a lambda
digitButtons.forEach {
    setOnClickListener(::handleClick)
}
```

And your handling code can use those lists from earlier too

```
fun handleClick(view: View) {
    when {
        view !is Button -> return
        view in digitButtons -> whateverYouDoWithThose(view)
    }
}
```

but personally I'd go for separate functions for each button type - for the digits, call a function that handles those. For an operator, call a different function. It's easier to read than one giant "a button was clicked here's how we handle each one" function, and it's more informative when you're assigning the click listeners too, since it reads like "when clicked, do this" and `handleDigitPressed` is better than `handleClick`, in my opinion anyway!

And `setOnClickListener(::clear)` is definitely better, you can immediately see what that button does without having to go look it up in the general click handler function. Having separate, well-named functions can make things a lot easier to parse