# How to solve this Error:Unresolved reference: text which is related to scope in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

### What I want to achieve:

I want to get the button text as parameter for the function

### What I want:

```kotlin
// Operators - setOnClickListener
btnDivide.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(it.text) }
btnMultiply.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(it.text) }
btnMinus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(it.text) }
btnPlus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(it.text) }
```

### What is working:

```kotlin
// Operators - setOnClickListener
btnDivide.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnDivide.text) }
btnMultiply.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnMultiply.text) }
btnMinus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnMinus.text) }
btnPlus.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator(btnPlus.text) }
```

### The problem that is appearing:

Error: `Unresolved reference: text`, when i am doing `it.text`

But inside setOnClickListener{ `it: View!` }, I saw this preview as it is generally shown. So I thought that, here `it` is refering to the button to which I am setting the `onClickListener`.

if there is any confusion about the question, please write in the comment. If my approach is wrong, share in the comments

Answer (score 1):

> So I thought that, here it is referring to the button to which I am setting the onClickListener.

Here, `it` is of type `View` and not of type `Button`, or whatever type of *specific* view type you want it to be, so because not all views have a `text` property (which means that `View` doesn't have something called `text`, but `Button` might), you can use something like this:

```
 btnDivide.setOnClickListener { viewModel.mountOperator((it as Button).text) }
```

where you can replace `Button` with whatever type of view it is.

`it as Button` is casting the `View` we get into our specific type, in your case I'm assuming this will be a button, but you can cast it to whatever type of view it actually is.

---

`it: View!` here does refer to the button you're setting the onClickListener to, but it's returned to you as a `View` and not of a more specific type

Answer (score 1):

Also to follow up on @a_local_nobody's answer, the reason it's just passing in a generic `View` and not the type you're setting the click listener on, is because you can create a single listener object/function and reuse it for all the things that need to handle clicks (which could be different subclasses of `View`)

So if you like, you could make one of those and use it instead of repeating the code for each button:

```
fun handleButtonClick(view: View) {
    if (view is Button) viewModel.mountOperator(view.text)
}

btnDivide.setOnClickListener { handleButtonClick(it) }
// or as a function reference
btnMultiply.setOnClickListener(::handleButtonClick)
```

---

And another thing you can do when you're assigning multiple identical click listeners (or doing the same anything to a bunch of things) is to just do a loop

```
listOf(btnDivide, btnMultiply, btnMinus, btnPlus).forEach {
    it.setOnClickListener { //bla bla }
}
```

that works for reusing a function reference or just creating a new one for each listener (like you're doing in your question) - it just saves you repeating yourself, it can be easier to read, and if you need to make changes you only have to do it in one place